# SonarQube Rule: Every Rule with an sample example are present?

Tags: sonarqube

**Agenda and reason to ask this question** : I was going through profile created by someone and want to remove false positive rules.

**Question :**

For example :

I want to understand below rule,

***"Correctness - Class defines methods which confuse Character with int parameters"***

**Where should i see details and examples?**

Thanks,
Roshankumar

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be in a SonarQube rule list context, the rule detail will give you this. To see it, click on the rule or right-arrow.

The descriptions for FindBugs rules can be terse at best, but this is an FB-contrib rule with a slightly longer description. However, it does not contain examples.